# Swift: Casting int tuples to custom type containing float vectors

Tags: swift, metal

**Both original answers to this questions are satisfactory but come to the solution in slightly different ways. I opted for the one that I found simpler to implement**

I'm attempting to translate some ObjectiveC, [from this apple metal doc/example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_a_render_pipeline_to_render_primitives), and metal code into swift but having some trouble with this bit:

here is the typedef I'm using, which is necessary so that the metal shaders can computer my vertex data (the float vectors from simd.h are significant):

```
#include <simd/simd.h>

typedef struct
{
  vector_float2 position;
  vector_float4 color;
} AAPLVertex;
```

In the objective C you can just do this to cast some data to this type:

```
static const AAPLVertex triangleVertices[] =
{
    // 2D positions,    RGBA colors
    { {  250,  -250 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
    { { -250,  -250 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1 } },
    { {    0,   250 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1 } },
};
```

But how do you do this in Swift? I've attempted this:

```
  private let triangleVertices = [
    ( (250,  -250), (1, 0, 1, 1) ),
    ( (-250,  -250), (1, 1, 0, 1) ),
    ( (0,  250), (0, 1, 1, 1) )
  ] as? [AAPLVertex]
```

but xcode tells me:

`Cast from '[((Int, Int), (Int, Int, Int, Int))]' to unrelated type '[AAPLVertex]' always fails`

and my app crashes on load.

Comment: You should at least link the relevant documentation, to save readers' time: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_a_render_pipeline_to_render_primitives

Comment: @Alexander thanks. I actually didn't want to burden the reader with too much information and this seems like it is potentially a more general question about the language than this specific example, but you're probably right.

Comment: It's non-obvious where `vector_float2` and `vector_float4` come from (to the uninitiated, like myself), whether they're a metal shader language thing or an ObjC thing, etc.

Comment: @Alexander good point, I'll throw the header import up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import simd

struct AAPLVertex {
    let position: float2
    let color: float4
}

let  triangleVertices: [AAPLVertex] = [
     // 2D positions,    RGBA colors
    .init(position: .init( 250, -250), color: .init(1, 0, 1, 1)),
    .init(position: .init(-250, -250), color: .init(1, 1, 0, 1)),
    .init(position: .init(   0, -250), color: .init(0, 1, 1, 1))]
```

Comment: It works well. I already define the struct in a C header file so that it can be used in the metal shaders so importing `simd` and defining the struct are unecessary. What is the .init's purpose here?

Comment: haha, sorry, didn't mean to come off as critical, just being clear. Thanks!

Comment: the `.init` replaces the type at the prefix.  AAPLVertex , float2
 and float4. Swift just infers the type that's being initialized

Comment: I didn't know init could be implicitly scoped like this. I think my approach of adding a convenience initializer is better in this case, but this is neat to know for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would implement it:

```
import simd

struct Vertex {
    var position: SIMD2<Float>
    var color: SIMD4<Float>
}

extension Vertex {
    init(x: Float, y: Float, r: Float, g: Float, b: Float, a: Float = 1.0) {
        self.init(position: SIMD2(x, y), color: SIMD4(r, g, b, a))
    }
}

let triangleVertices = [
    Vertex(x: +250, y: -250, r: 1, g: 0, b: 1),
    Vertex(x: -250, y: -250, r: 1, g: 1, b: 0),
    Vertex(x:    0, y: -250, r: 0, g: 1, b: 1),
]
```

However, I'm not sure to what extent the Swift native SIMD types are compatible with Metal, as compared to the [Objective C ones](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/simd_data_types?language=objc), though I suspect they're interoperable.

Comment: @I am importing the SIMD types and defining my Vertex data in a C header file so that they can be shared with my metal shaders and everything works!

Comment: Just be mindful of the alignment of simd types. `SIMD4<Float>` has an alignment of 16, so placing it after a member of type `SIMD2<Float>` could result in 8 bytes of padding being inserted. Furthermore, Swift makes no guarantees about struct member layout, so these members could hypothetically be reordered as well. If you're making assumptions elsewhere (e.g., if you're copying an array of vertices into a Metal buffer), it's best to declare the struct in C/Objective-C and import it via bridging. Then, the declared layout will be honored (though it might still be padded for alignment purposes).